# Google Classroom - How to list only created/updated/deleted courses

Tags: google-classroom

I am trying to create a google sync API(background API using scheduler) which basically updates my database courses with the google classroom courses.

The Google Classroom API does not seem to have a mechanism for fetching only create/update/delete courses. right now I am able to fetch all courses from google classrooms using google classrooms API but i want only created/updated/deleted courses list.

Also, can I call my API endpoint, if a course is created/updated/deleted into google classrooms course?

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list), it is not yet supported. You can restrict returned courses to those in one of the specified states **"only"** using [`courseStates`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#CourseState) parameter.

> Possible states a course can be in.
>
> - COURSE_STATE_UNSPECIFIED
> - ACTIVE
> - ARCHIVED
> - PROVISIONED
> - DECLINED
> - SUSPENDED

If the feature hasn't been requested yet, you can [file a feature request on the Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I want to keep update my database courses(which also have a status like you explained above), so I need all modified courses. I will file a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply on Google Issue Tracker after creating a feature request:-
**Google Issue Tracker Url:**
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74175718
**Reply:**
So, you're correct that we don't yet support returning the list of courses which have been updated since your last sync. I've changed this to a feature request to reflect that.

However, in case it's helpful to you, we do offer two things that might address some of your needs:
(1) Our courses.list endpoint (https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) guarantees that results are ordered by most recently created. So it should be easy to detect all the courses that have been created since the last sync by doing timestamp comparisons.
(2) If your sync job is running with the credentials of a domain administrator, you can use push notifications (https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications) to get updated when the rosters change for all courses in the domain (course creation will appear as a notification that the primary teacher has been added to the course, so you should be able to detect that as well).